# Javascript Sets Customize equals comparison

Tags: javascript, set, prototype

I need to use the javascript prototype Sets, to hold input suggestions without duplicates.

I would like to customize the comparison of when a set is created to not only exclude exact string matches, but also string matches that are different cases.

For example, currently in the set, there will be
`{English, Spanish}`
I would like to get rid of cases like
`{English, ENGLisH, english} as well.

How do I customize the prototype?

Comment: `.toLowerCase()` before added to set. or doing the customized comparison.

Comment: `.toUpperCase();` also works fine

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, the way the algorithm works is that.

I receive multiple arrays and instead of looping through to add them one by one, I just wanna concat and use the new([iterable]) to optimize speed. This is why i need to customize the structure